# Submitting form only working sometimes after implementing bootstrap styles ruby on rails 5

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

So I am trying to submit my form for a listing. I added carrierwave-aws and got my image uploader to work in the form, then after adding bootstrap styles to my form it seems to only submit *sometimes* and then other times I click the submit button and *nothing* happens. No errors in the console, no activity in the local host server. One time it works, the next it seems to freeze/break with no activity.

My googling has led me to think maybe its something to do with turbolinks, or a missing html tag (I dont think its the missing tag).

Here is my _form partial

```
<div class="card w-75 text-left form-card">
  <div class="card-body form-card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">


        <%= form_for @listing, multipart: true do |f| %>
        <% if listing.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(listing.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this listing from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% listing.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <% end %>



        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'ex. Mission Grove Plaza', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :street %>
          <%= f.text_field :street, placeholder: 'ex. 140 Main St.', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :suite_number %>
          <%= f.text_field :suite_number, placeholder: 'ex. Suite 145', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :city %>
          <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :state %>
          <%= f.select :state, ['California'], :prompt => 'Select One', class: 'form-control' %>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :zipcode %>
          <%= f.number_field :zipcode, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :building_type %>
          <%= f.text_field :building_type, placeholder: 'ex. Office, Retail, Industrial', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :available_sqft %>
          <%= f.number_field :available_sqft, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :year_built %>
          <%= f.number_field :year_built, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :asking_rate %>
          <%= f.number_field :asking_rate, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :transaction_type %>
          <%= f.text_field :transaction_type, placeholder: 'Lease or Sale', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :land_size %>
          <%= f.number_field :land_size, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :market %>
          <%= f.text_field :market, placeholder: 'ex. Riverside, Corona, Redlands', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            Upload main image(s) <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true, accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png" %>

          <p><em>Please upload all main images at once using shift+click to select all files you want to upload.</em></p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            Upload thumb image <%= f.file_field :thumb_image %>

          <p><em>You can only upload one thumb image.</em></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

here is my layout/application

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= @page_title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <meta name="keywords" content="<%= @seo_keywords %>"/>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">



    <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+Rails.application.credentials.google_maps_api_key %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= yield(:head_tags) %>
  </head>

  <body>
   <%= render 'shared/nav' %>

    <%= yield %>

    <%= alerts %>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is my application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery-ui
//= require activestorage
//= require cocoon
//= require gritter
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

function initMap(lat, lng) {
    var myCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapOptions = {
    center: myCoords,
    zoom: 13
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCoords,
    map: map
});
}
```

in my application.scss I have

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

and in my Gemfile I have

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'sassc-rails', '>= 2.0.0'
```

also here is my listing controller

```
    class ListingsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      access all: [:show, :index], user: {except: [:destroy, :new, :create, :update, :edit]}, site_admin: :all


      def index
        search_listings
        @page_title = "Mudge Advisor's | Listings"
      end

      def show
        @page_title = @listing.street
        @seo_keywords = @listing.set_address
      end

      def new
        @listing = Listing.new
      end

      def edit
      end

      def create
        @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @listing.save
            format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @listing.update(listing_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @listing }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @listing.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to listings_url, notice: 'Listing was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private

      def set_listing
        @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
      end

      def listing_params
        params.require(:listing).permit(:name,
                                        :street,
                                        :city,
                                        :state,
                                        :zipcode,
                                        :building_type,
                                        :available_sqft,
                                        :year_built,
                                        :asking_rate,
                                        :land_size,
                                        :market,
                                        { images: []},
                                        :thumb_image,
                                        :suite_number,
                                        :transaction_type
                                        )
      end

      def search_listings
        if params[:query]
          search_words = params[:query]
          if !params[:query].empty?
            @listings = Listing.kinda_matching(search_words)
          else
            flash[:notice] = "Search can't be empty"
            @listings = Listing.all
          end
          @listings
        else
        @listings = Listing.all
        end
      end
    end


and listing model

class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  validates :street,
            :city,
            :state,
            :zipcode,
            :country,
            :building_type,
            :asking_rate,
            :market,
            :transaction_type,
                          presence: true

  validates :street, uniqueness: true

  mount_uploader :thumb_image, ListingUploader
  mount_uploaders :images, ListingUploader

  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :kinda_matching,
                                    :against => [:name,
                                                :street,
                                                :city,
                                                :state,
                                                :zipcode,
                                                :building_type,
                                                :suite_number,
                                                :transaction_type,
                                                :market
                                                ],
                                    :using => {
                                      :tsearch => {:prefix => true}
                                  }

  geocoded_by :set_address
  after_validation :geocode

  def set_address
    "#{self.street}, #{self.city}, #{self.state}, #{self.zipcode.to_s}, #{self.country}"
  end
end
```

here is my server

```
Started GET "/listings/50/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-05 19:33:57 +0100
Processing by ListingsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"50"}
  Listing Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 50], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:61
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_user_concern.rb:5
  Rendering listings/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered listings/_form.html.erb (13.8ms)
  Rendered listings/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (17.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 246ms (Views: 235.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

I know it's a lot and if you're still with me thanks so much. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was either bootstrap or carrierwave uploaded breaking my form. I solved the problem by deleting bootstrap from my entire app, and also deleting carrierwave and upgrading to active storage for image uploading (so much better than carrierwave) and then re implementing bootstrap. Now I’m golden, thanks the response!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your computer?

I realize this is a very simplistic answer, but it can sometimes work wonders.

Good luck resolving : )

Dan